# How to remove the padding from an image after the image's width changes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is too create a small gallery of pictures but when I shrink the size of the image with CSS using width: 15px, the space between the columns stays the same making the images very spread out instead of making the container smaller

```css
.gallery-dog-img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;

  }

.gallery{
  padding: 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

.dog-cell {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<section class="gallery bg-primary">
  <div class="container-lg dog-gallery-container">
    <div class="row align-items-center dog-images-row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3">
      <div class="col  d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="{% static '/images/home_dog_carousel/dog4.jpeg' %}" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Is there a way to make the container smaller to better fit the smaller size or remove the padding left over from the image's original size?

Comment: What exactly do you want to be smaller? Should the blue background fit the content or should the background keep its 100%-width and you want to center the small pics in the middle? Or do you want the pictures to be responsive to grow and shrink with the window size instead of setting them to 15px?

Comment: @EduDev I want to decrease the amount of space between the columns while changing the images to 15px. Without the size change the images are just too large. The blue background doesn't need to keep its 100%-width. I'm trying to keep all the images in the same view without having to scroll to see them all.

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing will often happen in Bootstrap when adding additional CSS that relates to **layout**. Mostly because Bootstrap has it all pre-written and by adding more we're interferring with it more than anything else.

I think you should try Bootstrap `gutter` (link below).

`g-1` is added to the first line but you can use `g-0` to `g-5`

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-1">
   <div class="col">
      <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Gutters --> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to keep the pics small and reduce the gaps between the columns to show a grid-like pattern.

The bootstrap containers work well with responsive images scaling them according to the cell-size. Since you don't want your images to scale, you have to reduce the width of the container, e.g. by choosing `fit-content` or a size other than the original 100%. To do that you have to [overwrite](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) the original boostrap CSS by adding `!important` to your CSS changes. Just be careful with the use of `!important` because it can get quite messy if you lose track of the overwritten parts.

To handle the gaps between the columns and rows, you can easily use the [BS gutter-classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/), e.g. `g-3`.

```css
.gallery{
  padding: 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}
.dog-gallery-container{
  width: fit-content !important;
}
.dog-cell {
  padding-right:0 !important;
  padding-left:0 !important;
}
.gallery-dog-img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:0;

  }
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<section class="gallery bg-primary">
  <div class="container dog-gallery-container">
    <div class="row align-items-center dog-images-row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
      <div class="col  d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="{% static '/images/home_dog_carousel/dog4.jpeg' %}" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```